# Supporting Hyperplane and tangent

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, convex-geometry

Let $K \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a convex,compact with non empty interior

What is the regularity of $\partial K$ such that any supporting hyperplane of $K$ is the tangent?

this property is obvious if $K$ is a Disque, I guess that if $\partial K$ is $C^{2}$ we can obtain this property 
Thank you in advance for any answer, comments, suggestions or references.

the definition of the supporting hyperplane:

Let $K$ be a closed and bounded convex set in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then a hyperplane $H$is called a supporting hyperplane of $K$ if and only if

(1) $K$is contained in one of the halfspaces of $H$, and

(2) $K\cap H \neq \emptyset $.

Comment: @Henry.L did you have any idea? I think you gave a  similar question